# Migrating from AS2 to AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript-2

I would like to know from someone who have already done that, any recommendations and things I have to take a special look, I have seen some articles related to the topic, googled it, etc...

but I would like the advice from stackoverflower x)

I already know object oriented programming in c++, using classes and etc, but I can't quite understand AS3 packages and stuff, but i'm very familiarized with AS2.

Thanks

Comment: not really a question, i would like advices from someone who have already done that, so I can start learning the best way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Drop everything you know, start fresh. AS2 is different than AS3. Don't try to do the AS2 thing with AS3.
2. Read & Learn the Adobe LiveDocs
3. Learn how the display list works.
4. Learn AS3 coding standards, write clean readable code
5. Learn how to use common actionscript libraries, TweenLite, Gaia framework, RobotLegs, Temple Library, Pure MVC, Away3D, as3corelib etc.
6. Never ever code inside the Flash IDE actionspanel, there are really nice actionscript editors like FlashDevelop, FDT, FlashBuilder, IntelliJ.

Comment: _"Learn the Adobe LiveDocs"_?? Well, keep in mind that Adobe's docs for AS3 are, though extensive, not complete and you will come across many _many_ situations where the docs do not give you the info they should.

Comment: Well I think if you know what IS included in the docs, you don't need them that often; Then you probably have learned enough to find own solutions or get another solution elsewhere. I think its a good starting point for those who want to learn about actionscript 3.

Comment: I think what Mark is getting at is, familiarity with the API, so you know what is possible.

Comment: Yes, you need to know enough to be able to know when to keep digging when they are incomplete or (worse) inaccurate.

Answer (score 0):

My experience migrating from AS2 to AS3 has been pretty smooth, so smooth that I would never go back and squirm at the thought of maintaining old AS2 code.

Firstly I would get familiar with the display list, here is a good [article](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/display_list_programming_as3.html).

Then I would gain an understanding of the new types in AS3, especially the difference between Number, int and uint as you don't need to lump everything in Number anymore.

Do some reading up on the event system and how you can capture events that have bubbled up from other objects, and how you can use capture and stop them propagating further, and how to avoid unnecessary clicks on nested objects in buttons you create.

Like you say you already know OOP, so I would then suggest limiting timeline code as much as possible, write everything in classes.

XML is handled using e4x which makes xml parsing trivial, you will find this a breeze to work with compared to AS2.

The drawing api is now contained in a graphics library accessible through many display objects.

Get to know a good framework, I highly recommend [pure MVC AS3](http://trac.puremvc.org/PureMVC_AS3/)

Finally for animation - there can be only one library - [Greensock TweenMax](http://www.greensock.com/tweenmax/) AS3 of course ; )

**EDIT :**

I have looked around for some resources that I think will be of interest to you, I based these choices on my experiences and what I believe are key areas of research:

[Presentation on AS3 by Grant Skinner](http://gskinner.com/talks/as3workshop/) - Excellent overview that you can refer to time and time again.

[Getting Started with ActionScript 3.0](http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/as3withflashcs3/) - Comprehensive approach to using AS3 with Flash CS3.

[Senoculars tips of the day](http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?223798-ActionScript-3-Tip-of-the-Day) - because you already code in AS2 you should understand a lot of these tips and how they differ in AS3.

Comment: Very nice, thank you for your advices, and btw do you have any recommended exercises to start doing in order to pratice the as3?

Comment: Yes, I will dig some out for you later today

Comment: I have had a look around for some resources which helped me over the years, hopefully they will be useful for you. I would also recommend Essential Actionscript 3 by Colin Moock, that book was first as3 book i ever read.